# Smartcard TLP224 protocol specification

Tags: protocols, smartcard

I am working on the Smart Card Device driver.

The card, that I work with works over protocol `TLP224`.

Where can I find an full specification of this protocol?

I tried to look up over the internet, but only found some docs,
that regards to a specific card readers.

Is there any full specification of `TLP224`?

Answer (score 0):

How I read [GCI400 specification](http://www.datasheetarchive.com/indexer.php?file=DSARS0019012.pdf&dir=Datasheets-UD7&keywords=TLP224&database=user-highscore#), this is a communication protocol between host and card reader. I never heard from a card supporting this. Since it is patented, it is probably not publicly available but only after buying a license, signing a non-disclosure agreement or something like that. If you have I choice I would recommend to switch to a reader supporting an open interface.